# Selfies on the Moon

Tags: vacuum, moonwalking

Number 8 on [this](http://www.cracked.com/photoplasty_1364_32-ridiculous-ways-modern-media-wouldve-covered-history_p5/) *Cracked* PhotoPlasty article made me wonder - what would happen to an unprotected smartphone on the moon?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Is it about being exposed to vacuum, or temperature, ...?

Comment: Answers for both would be interesting. This is just an idle question.

Comment: Day side or night side?

Comment: Day side or night? If you're talking the solar effects in the smart phone then the moon doesn't have a dark side! That's only the way we see it.

Answer (score 1):

Meaningful differences between Earth surface environment and Moon surface:

No atmosphere:

- Heat cannot be dissipated by convection. The temperature due to the components will increase. The battery (lithium) may explode above 80°C.
- Screen may be difficult to read, because the light will be bright (directly exposed to the Sun).

No radiation protection:

- Chips are sensitive to radiation and may be [disturbed](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS4220/h11/undervisningsmateriale/forelesninger-vhdl/Radiation%20effects%20on%20space%20electronics.pdf). This is because insulation/conduction state in semi-conductors will be disrupted by the energy from the ionized particles and electromagnetic radiation) Reboot may be required frequently. Chips may also be destructed. Normally chips used in space are [hardened](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_hardening) to sustain ionizing radiation.

Gravity 1/6th on the Moon:

- Gravity and acceleration sensors will be inaccurate.

No GPS, no wifi, no network:

- Location cannot be determined.
- Communications cannot be established.

Devices used on the Moon will experience the same constraints that on board satellites and space probes.

Comment: Its obvious, but you could point out that the microphone and speaker wont work (well), because sound can only be transmitted by touch.

Comment: Would vacuum affect the glue and plastic?

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi. Yep, very good point! Sound propagation requires a medium. But has the user must have a helmet, it would be difficult to get something from the speaker, or the mike.

Comment: @JoeL. Together with the intense radiation, eventually, yes.

Comment: @JoeL. Vacuum will not break plastic (which will only release gases), but high energy particles (e.g. from the Sun) will definitely degrade plastic and glue.

Comment: @mins The stuff that it releases as gas is not "extra" in the plastic...

Comment: The moon's surface actually doesn't reflect light all that well. On average, it reflects about <a href="http://the-moon.wikispaces.com/Albedo>11%</a> of the light that hits it. The angle that you are looking at it from does matter though, because the regolith has a lot of glass in it that has a retroreflector effect at the right angle.

Comment: @briligg: I stand corrected. Thanks. Fixing.

Comment: It's one of those tricky relative things really. The sky is jet black and the sun is much stronger, both because there is no atmosphere, so i imagine human eyes feel a lot of glare from the ground, anyhow.

Comment: @briligg: Yes absolutely, and in addition I assumed the regolith would be very light compared to our brown soil.

Comment: Smartphones are designed to avoid exploding, so generally they shut themselves down when the temperature gets too high. Once it shuts down, the heat will radiate away so the battery will probably never explode due to temperature alone. On the other hand, the vacuum will increase the physical strain on the battery package. I don't know how much of an effect this would have.